# getaddrinfo sorting IPv4 before IPv6 for localhost?

Tags: networking, ipv6, getaddrinfo

I wrote a very simple test program for getaddrinfo:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *res, *rp;
    char hoststr[64], servstr[8];

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    getaddrinfo(NULL, "9998", &hints, &res);
    for (rp = res; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next) {
        getnameinfo(rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen, hoststr, sizeof(hoststr),
                servstr, sizeof(servstr), NI_NUMERICHOST | NI_NUMERICSERV);
        printf("%s:%s\n", hoststr, servstr);
    }
}
```

When I compile and run this program, it's giving the IPv4 address before the IPv6 address:

```
# gcc -o getaddrinfo getaddrinfo.c
# ./getaddrinfo 
0.0.0.0:9998
:::9998
```

As far as I can tell from other sources, IPv6 addresses are supposed to be preferred over IPv4. I'm using the default /etc/gai.conf which implies that IPv6 should be preferred over IPv4. So why is getaddrinfo sorting this way?

```
# ip addr show lo
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Answer (score 1):

From the man page:

> If  the  AI_PASSIVE  flag  is  specified in hints.ai_flags, and node is
>          NULL,  then  the  returned  socket  addresses  will  be  suitable   for
>          bind(2)ing  a  socket  that  will  accept(2) connections.  The returned
>          socket address will contain the "wildcard address" (INADDR_ANY for IPv4
>          addresses, IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT for IPv6 address).  The wildcard address is
>          used by applications (typically servers) that intend to accept  connections  on  any  of  the host's network addresses.  If node is not NULL,
>          then the AI_PASSIVE flag is ignored.

The behavior you're describing is for when you use `getaddrinfo()` to look up a name in preparation to make an outgoing connection. Because you're doing the reverse, looking up a local address to bind for a service, the order the addresses are presented is irrelevant.