# getaddrinfo with fist NULL parameter gives first IPv4 instead of IPv6

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I am facing the same problem as this OP: [getaddrinfo sorting IPv4 before IPv6 for localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49537694/7248819)

Though there were no understandable answer's, why does `getaddrinfo(NULL, ...)` with `AI_PASSIVE` flag returns first IPv4 then IPv6?

Answer (score 1):

> I am facing the same problem as this OP

What problem?  The behavior you and the other OP describe is within the behavior documented for `getaddrinfo()`.  If you want only IPv6 addresses, then you can specify that in the hints structure passed to that function.  If you want to accommodate both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, then you cannot safely make assumptions about the relative order in which they will be returned.  You then have at least two reasonable alternatives if you prefer (say) IPv6, but are willing to fall back to IPv4:

1. Make a request for (only) IPv6 addresses.  If that does not yield any usable address then make a separate request for IPv4 addresses.
2. Make a request without specifying an address family, and simply be prepared to scan past IPv4 addresses in the returned list in search of an acceptable IPv6 address.

Either way, proper use of `getaddrinfo()` *always* requires you to check each returned address to determine whether it meets your requirements, until you find one that does or you exhaust the list.

There is no particular "why" for the order of addresses, other than simply how your C library's implementors chose to do things.